# Instagram post specific user source, Where did the impression come from?

Tags: javascript, php, instagram, instagram-api

I'm trying to see if it is possible to determine which hashtags brought a user to a specific post. For analytics reasons, it would be very helpful to see which hashtags brought the most traffic to a specific post or account.

e.g.

- Post 123456 has 60 impressions.
- Out of 60 impressions, 20 came from #Coffee
- Out of 60 impressions, 40 came from #CoffeeIntoCode

Is this even possible? I can't find anything specific in the Instagram API.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: If it isn't mentioned in the API, I would say no, it isn't possible. Instagram has really limited their API in recent years.

Comment: That's a shame. Thanks for your input.